# How to seperate commas and values in a column using SQL server

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

Task-1: Please help me with a query or stored procedure to split the comma values.

Task-2: What best can be done with ROW1 data?

Column-A            Column-B

1. Vildagliptin, Exenatide  ,5075,,4085,
2. Canakinumab  ,3743,
3. Canagliflozin    ,3742,
4. Canakinumab  ,3743,

Comment: You could use for example [DelimitedSplit8k](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/Tally+Table/72993/) but how can we know what you should do with ROW1 data?

Answer (score 0):

Try like this, (Without using function)

```
SELECT [Column-A],
LTRIM(RTRIM(m.n.value('.[1]','varchar(8000)'))) AS [Column-B]
FROM
(
SELECT [Column-A],CAST('<XMLRoot><RowData>' + REPLACE([Column-B],',','</RowData><RowData>') + '</RowData></XMLRoot>' AS XML) AS x
FROM   <YourTable>
)t
CROSS APPLY x.nodes('/XMLRoot/RowData')m(n)
```